# error using biomaRt: Error in `mutate()` and `dplyr::select()`

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate, biomart

hope you are fine! I am having an error i never had using biomaRt.
Here is the code I am using and the error I am seeing:

```
`> library("biomaRt")
> # release 88 of Ensembl is March 2017
> #https://www.ensembl.org/info/website/archives/index.html
> ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "ensembl", 
+                       dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", 
+                       mirror = "useast")
> annot2 <- getBM(attributes=c('ensembl_gene_id', 'chromosome_name', 'start_position', 'end_position', 'description', 'strand','external_gene_name'), 
+                 #filters ='ensembl_gene_id', 
+                 #values = gene_ids, 
+                 mart = ensembl)
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `rpath = unname(bfcrpath(x, rids = rids))`.
Caused by error in `dplyr::select()`:
! <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Using an
          ^
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `rpath = unname(bfcrpath(x, rids = rids))`.
Caused by error in `dplyr::select()`:
! <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Using an
          ^
---
Backtrace:
  1. biomaRt::getBM(...)
 22. dplyr:::select.data.frame(., rid, field)`
```

I tryed to load again biomaRt, but nothing changed
.

This is my sessionInfo()

```
`> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.3.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] biomaRt_2.46.3      BiocManager_1.30.20 dplyr_1.0.9        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9           dbplyr_2.2.1         pillar_1.8.1         compiler_4.0.3       prettyunits_1.1.1    progress_1.2.2       tools_4.0.3         
 [8] bit_4.0.5            BiocFileCache_1.14.0 RSQLite_2.2.15       memoise_2.0.1        lifecycle_1.0.1      tibble_3.1.7         pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[15] rlang_1.0.4          DBI_1.1.3            cli_3.4.0            rstudioapi_0.14      curl_5.0.0           parallel_4.0.3       xfun_0.31           
[22] fastmap_1.1.1        withr_2.5.0          xml2_1.3.3           httr_1.4.5           stringr_1.4.1        rappdirs_0.3.3       askpass_1.1         
[29] hms_1.1.2            IRanges_2.24.1       generics_0.1.3       vctrs_0.4.1          S4Vectors_0.28.1     stats4_4.0.3         bit64_4.0.5         
[36] tidyselect_1.2.0     glue_1.6.2           Biobase_2.50.0       R6_2.5.1             fansi_1.0.3          AnnotationDbi_1.52.0 XML_3.99-0.13       
[43] limma_3.46.0         purrr_0.3.4          blob_1.2.3           magrittr_2.0.3       ellipsis_0.3.2       BiocGenerics_0.36.1  assertthat_0.2.1    
[50] utf8_1.2.3           tinytex_0.44         stringi_1.7.6        openssl_2.0.3        cachem_1.0.6         crayon_1.5.2        `
```

Anyone knows what's happening? thanks a lot in advance!
Chiara

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when using dplyr version 1.0.10 with biomaRt.

I resolved it by updating dplyr with `install.packages('dplyr')` and reinstalling biomaRt with `BiocManager::install('biomaRt', force=TRUE)`

Now get_BM() works as expected.

`packageVersion('biomaRt')`
[1] '2.50.3'

`packageVersion('dplyr')`
[1] '1.1.4'